# Claims are empty

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, claims-based-identity

I need to get some information from the user from the Claims. 
I have this in my controller method

```
var MyClaimsPrincipal = (ClaimsPrincipal)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
```

but it always returns empty

[image]

Here is my `Startup.Auth` class

[image]

The strange thing is that this code was worked before, the Claims were filled from the token claims and suddenly this is not working.

the token is present in the request, and if I decode it, i see the claims
[image]

Any advise is appreciated

I've rechecked and the app Id-s are correct, the custom policy name is correct.

This is the `Startup.Auth class`

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // These values are pulled from web.config
    public static string AadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AadInstance"];
    public static string Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    public static string ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    public static string SignUpSignInPolicy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId"];
    public static string DefaultPolicy = SignUpSignInPolicy;

    /*
     * Configure the authorization OWIN middleware 
     */
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // Accept only those tokens where the audience of the token is equal to the client ID of this app
            ValidAudience = ClientId,
            AuthenticationType = Startup.DefaultPolicy,
            NameClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier",
            ValidIssuer = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/iss"
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // This SecurityTokenProvider fetches the Azure AD B2C metadata & signing keys from the OpenIDConnect metadata endpoint
            AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy)))
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using this configuration in the frontend part:

```
         clientID: 'id',
         authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignInWithAAD/v2.0/",
        scopes: ["openid"],
```

and this in the API

```
  <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={1}" />
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="tenantname.onmicrosoft.com" /> 
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="id" />   
<add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignInWithAAD" />
```

Comment: Sounds like your authentication handler didn't run? Could you show how it is configured?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Could you add the code directly into the question as code, not as an image?

Comment: I've added as code

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this code

```
var MyClaimsPrincipal = (ClaimsPrincipal)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
```

with something like this

```
var currentClaimsPrincipal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;

if( currentClaimsPrincipal != null && currentClaimsPrincipal.Claims != null)
{
    var myClaimsPrincipal = new ClaimsIdentity(currentClaimsPrincipal.Claims);
}
```

OR if you're not looking to instantiate a new ClaimsIdentity, simply use the ClaimsPrincipal.Current

```
var MyClaimsPrincipal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
```

Here's a good reference on GitHub:

[Home Controller for Azure Active Directory Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/blob/master/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet/Controllers/HomeController.cs)

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```